# Unit testing Prism based WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xunit

I want to unit test a Prism based WPF application. It is a huge application with multiple projects. Each project is based on MVVM design pattern that is it has ViewModel/Views. This application uses Bootstrapper for initialization, uses regions concept and has event handling.

I tried using xunit. I took one project and added a corresponding test project where I tried to implement one test case. In the test case, I created an instance of View class (code behind) and tried to invoke a method from that class. I got the below errors:

```
*****************

------ Run test started ------
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.3423646]   Discovering: Demo.Test
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.2217151]   Discovered:  Demo.Test
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.2260195]   Starting:    Demo.Test
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5700093]     TestClassLibrary.TestDemo.TestCase1 [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5722687]       System.InvalidOperationException : The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5739943]       Stack Trace:
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5749537]            at System.Windows.Input.InputManager..ctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5754038]            at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.GetCurrentInputManagerImpl()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5757829]            at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation..ctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5762326]            at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FrameworkServices..ctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5766521]            at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EnsureFrameworkServices()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5771316]            at System.Windows.FrameworkElement..ctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5775379]            at System.Windows.Controls.Control..ctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5792034]            at System.Windows.Controls.UserControl..ctor()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5796505]            at Demo.Views.DemoLandingPage..ctor(IDemoViewModel vwModel, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, ISharedService sharedService)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5801319]         Demo.Test\Class1.cs(65,0): at TestClassLibrary.TestDemo.<TestCase1>b__0_0()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5805993]            at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5810366]            at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5814870]            at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5819703]            at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5825284]            at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5831148]            at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5834395]            at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5837782]            at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5842970]            at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5848709]            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5852488]            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5857359]            at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5863023]            at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5867150]            at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5872700]            at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5877817]            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5883386]            at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5889004]            at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5894200]            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5899856]            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5905323]            at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5910927]            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherOperation operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5915975]            at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.5921129]         Demo.Test\Class1.cs(63,0): at TestClassLibrary.TestDemo.TestCase1()
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.6178918]   Finished:    Demo.Test
========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:03.1364452) ==========

*****************
```

This is the test case code:

```
************* Class1.cs ******
namespace TestClassLibrary
{
    public class TestDemo
    {
[Fact]
        public void TestCase1()
        {
                if (Application.Current == null)
                {
                    if (System.Windows.Application.Current == null)
                    {
                        new System.Windows.Application { ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown };
                    }
                }

(LINE 63)                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
                {
(LINE 65)                    DemoLandingPage dem = new DemoLandingPage(null, null, null);
                    List<string> countryList = dem.GetCountryList("CountryList");
                    bool ret = searchCountry("Test", countryList);
                    Assert.True(ret == true);
                }));

        }

        bool searchCountry(string country, List<string> list)
        {
            return list.Contains(country);
        }    

*************
```

I would like to know:

Is it possible to unit test Prism based WPF application? If so, could you please let me know what should be my approach to test this application. Any pointers or documents/links would be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: we usually test model. Not even viewmodel.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. However, you should avoid using the `Application` class in your unit tests. You should only test your models and maybe view-models. Unit-testing of views usually makes no sense and is pretty awkward. Use UI testing tools for that.

Comment: One of the main benefits of using the MVVM pattern is that you can test your application logic in isolation without the views. So why are you creating an instance of a view in your unit test? It seems like you should do some reading on MVVM. If you need to unit test the views you have done something wrong. These shouldn't contain any logic that is not purely view related.

Comment: Thanks guys for the pointers.. @mm8, I created an instance of view to test a function which populates data for the view. I understood that I should be testing the models and not the view.

Comment: A quick question, what UI testing tools I can use to test the UI? Also, is it fine to use xunit to test the models?